# ASCII code printing logic

Tags: c++, c

I did write this program but now I am little bit confused about it. In the code given below I did writ two different statements which print string on the screen, first one did not print anything but second one print a symbol.

```
#include<iostream.h>
main(){
       int i = 1; char c;
       cout << c << endl;
       while (i <= 255){
         c = i;
         cout << c << endl;
         i++;
       }
}
```

Please explain me logic of this program. I am beginner of 'C' language so please explain it to me in details.
Thanks

Comment: What do you want an uninitialized `char` to print as?

Comment: actually i was printing ascii table, and now i am doing practices with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, as in your program you haven't initialised char c;

It must be initialised or hold some value before being printed!

```
   int i; char c;
   i = 1;
   cout << c << endl;     // initialsise c=something of char-type;
   c = i;
   cout << c << endl;     //as initialised,so prints something
```

Second, as you have initialised this char variable c. Hence,it prints some symbol,probably an ASCII character!

Comment: but why it prints symbol (☺), why i cannot print "1" instead of symbol (☺)?

Comment: @shujat7-Because,it is of a char-type.A character type is a symbol-type value.What you are trying to input is that you are providing i=1,but char variables work on ASCII values.Hence,it'll refer to ASCII value of 1,which is `'SOH---Start of Heading'`.You need to refer to this-->>http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @shujat7-To print 1,store ASCII value of `49` in i.And then do `c=i;` And finally do `cout<<c<<endl;` You'll get 1.!

Answer (score 0):

First `cout << c << endl;` prints unitialized value `c` (it might be zero, so you don't see anything). But second call of this instructions prints value `(char) 1` (you can see it).

Comment: but why it prints symbol (☺), why i cannot print "1" instead of symbol (☺)?

Comment: Because it is first symbol in ASCII table. You can print "1", but for it you have to print `int` instead of `char` (try it: `int i=1; cout << i << endl;`)

Answer (score 0):

When you initially printed the character 'c' then it does not have any value. When nothing is initialized in a character then it takes garbage value. Afterwards

```
int i=1;
char c = i;
```

It stores 1 in variable 'c' but as it is a character so on printing 'c' it shows the ASCII value of 1 which is ☺

It is same as doing->

```
cout << (char)i <<endl;
```

if you want to print the ASCII table then this code may help

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
     cout<<"ASCII VALUE OF "<<i<<" is "<<(char)i <<endl;
}
```

Comment: Not initialized value might be not NULL. You can't be sure it is NULL (it depends on compilator options).